# Adobe Illustrator draws multiple shapes while drawing single shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to draw single shape using shape drawing tool in Illustrator but,
when I hold click and slide my mouse, it draws multiple shapes. How can I resolve this issue ?[image: here is the screenshot of the issue.]

Comment: Do me a favor, select the Elipse Tool and simply click on the artboard, insert two values and hit enter. Does it still draw more than one shape?

Answer (score 9):

Well, This usually happens when using the <kbd>Tilde</kbd> (<kbd>~</kbd>) key.

[image]

It's a "**Continuous Duplicates Based on Mouse Movement**" function and combined with Alt/Option, Shift/Command and spacebar you can create new and complex effects.

**Are you sure your Tilde key is not pressed or locked somehow?
Also, try drawing a circle while holding the Tilde key pressed...**

I'm asking cause I don't know of a setting in Illustrator that will do this automatically...

[image]

> PS: Here's an article where you can [read about it.](http://www.vectordiary.com/tips-and-tricks/illustrator-trick-2-tilde-fun/)

Comment: Still happens on macOS in Illustrator CC 2017. If none of the above works, you'll have to reboot. Relaunching Illustrator doesn't cut it. I even upgraded to CC 2018 and it imported the bug for me, so it's some OS level issue. If you've come this far, reboot!

Comment: TIL ▲ what an interesting feature, I wonder if/how I'll ever use it.

Comment: @WELZ Well, I never found a use for it so far :))

Comment: Drawing action lines.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I had the same issue, restarting illustrator wouldn't work. I held <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> and dragged the mouse and it went away. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Not tilda, it's tilde https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tilde FTFY

Comment: Chances are your Tilde key was stuck. By pressing it again, you "unstuck" it. Restarting typically doesn't help because this is an issue with the keyboard itself, not the OS - at least every time I've ever seen it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things but if you press SHIFT + TILDE KEY you can unlock it and ai will stop repeating the patterns. I tried with SHIFT + ALT + TILDE KEY but it wouldnt work. So if youre stuck I guess just try SHIFT + TILDE KEY. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem "replacing the preferences" with this solution:

- Close down Illustrator and press Ctrl+Alt+Shift/Cmd+Option+Shift before opening it again (easy but irreversible);

Thanks to this article and Jacob Bugge post: https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/multiple-shapes-behaviour-in-the-shape-builder-tool/td-p/10840695

Hope does the same to you

Answer (score 0):

If you have Problems with the tilde on the Mac keyboard I found a solution that works for me.

Change the keyboard language to " ENGLISH DVOARK"

and hit: SHIFT+CTRL+^

and than change the keyboard language to your regular.

It works!